# How to re-connect the connected WIFI before in Xamarin Forms(iOS)？

Tags: ios, xamarin.forms

My project is Xamarin Forms in iOS device, and that using WIFI to work with other devices. I want to know whether it is possible to know the current connected ssid name first. If my app loses the link, can it silently try to reconnect to the WiFi without the user having to do anything?
[Here is my logic diagram](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4ngI6.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use DependencyService to get a SSID name, you could refer to [Xamarin.Forms DependencyService](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/dependency-service/introduction)
In your service, try some code like this:

```
string ssid = "";
string[] supportedInterfaces;
StatusCode status = CaptiveNetwork.TryGetSupportedInterfaces(out supportedInterfaces);
if ((status = CaptiveNetwork.TryGetSupportedInterfaces(out supportedInterfaces)) == StatusCode.OK)
{
    foreach (var item in supportedInterfaces)
    {
        NSDictionary info;
        status = CaptiveNetwork.TryCopyCurrentNetworkInfo(item, out info);
        if (status == StatusCode.OK)
        {
            ssid = info[CaptiveNetwork.NetworkInfoKeySSID].ToString();
        }                       
    }
}
```

In your info.plist, you should add this key:

```
<key>NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription</key>
<string>Your Description</string>
```

Once you get the SSID name (and password), you could use NEHostspotConfiguration to make a connection.

```
NEHotspotConfiguration hotspotConfiguration = new NEHotspotConfiguration(ssid,pwd,false);
hotspotConfiguration.JoinOnce = true;
NEHotspotConfigurationManager.SharedManager.ApplyConfiguration(hotspotConfiguration, (NSError error) =>
{
    if (error != null)
    {
        if (error?.LocalizedDescription == "already associated.")
        {
            IsConnected = true;
        }
        else
        {
            IsConnected = false;
        }
    }
    else
    {
        IsConnected = true;
    }
});
```

You may also enable Access WiFi information, Hotspot capability of you App ID at the Apple Developer Portal and add them in your Entitlements.plist. Don't forget to regenerate your provisioning file. Hope my answer could help you~

Comment: Thx, bro! Sorry, I need at least 15 reputation to cast a vote...